# Report recursively calling itself

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am compiling a document with SSRS best practices for our team and have been asked to put an example of a report recursively calling itself and the reasons why it such a report may be created.

I tried to look it up but couldn't find something too helpful. Would be great if someone could help me with this and provide a list of reasons for a recursive report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good example of a recursive report would be displaying data that is hierarchical. Such as a file tree, or a manager/employee structure.

Comment: Thanks. Could there be any other reasons like creating automatic snapshots of the report or constantly checking the connection with the DB?

Comment: I wouldn't consider that recursion and in those situations I would just schedule the report to run every X minutes. That way if it fails on one instance it will restart at the next instance where if you have a report that is continuously running and it fails it will not restart. Also resource-wise that seems wasteful.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This link explains how to configure it (I haven't tried it myself), but to help other people in the future. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx